Need help, tools required to demolish half wall at the entrance of kitchen

Hi, I need to remove this kitchen separating half wall, could you please advise steps, tools, tips how can I do that?
Thanks,

This is a very broad question and likely to be closed if you do not [edit] it to ask something more focused. Basically, you need to be sure nothing electrical or plumbing is in it, then cut it off with a saw, then repair the remaining surfaces. If you have an issue with any of those steps, ask about that. Otherwise, search here and then maybe Youtube and get some ideas of where you'll run into trouble.

Thanks for the quick reply , I have edited my question, I would need list of tools to demolish this half wall.

Strongly depends on how much fun you want to have destroying it...

What is that little electrical wire used for? It looks like it could be for telephones and/or internet.

That wire is to alert door opening, it’s very old and doesn’t work, I am thinking to remove it as well, thanks for pointing out.

Check for electrical outlets
Philips screwdriver, to unscrew the drywall, or nail extracting hammer in case it is nailed.
Kitchen magnet to find the screws/nails
Utility knife to cut drywall
You might or might not need a saw to cut off the horizontal 2x4
Drywall and floor repair materials

The floor repair might be the hardest.  OP will be lucky if that wall was built on top of the tiles(?)

I don’t see any tiles underneath that half wall :(
